# How can I get an alert me if ping is not sent from windows service I created?

Tags: monitoring, ping, application

Let me explain the problem. I created a windows service that should run a method every minute, but it seems to fail at random times for an unknown reason. The application doesn't crash but some how a method in the program stops working correctly.

I would like to ping a website url every time the method runs.
Is there any web  service that could alert me if a ping is not received from my application every minute?

Or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Yes, there are services that do precisely this. Use search terms "cron job monitoring" to find them.

Answer (score 1):

There is https://deadmanssnitch.com/, but the resolution is 15 minutes.

You might instead consider integrating your service with something like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) to report failures, like an unreported exception.